# How to delay an output in Python, while still doing things in the background

Tags: python

So i am currently working on a command terminal project. basically a place to send emails, get game stats, translate stuff, and even give reminders. I was trying to make a reminder command that asked how long to remind you in, and then have a delay before sending them an email to remind. So i have tryed to import time and do time.sleep(1), but it means they can do anything else until its over. So i also saw a similar question here that asked about the same thing, so i tryed some of the suggestions they gave there, but no luck. The suggestion i tryed gave this code, `from time import sleep, time` but it said no module named sleep. Anyway i cant find anything that will work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the link that doesn't helped?

Comment: and please format your code, use proper grammar.

Comment: There is a module named sleep. are you sure you typed it right?

Comment: im pretty sure i did, but i can double check

Comment: yes i did, and this was the output ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5838ed259482> in <module>
     70 if len(username) > 1:
     71         print("acsess granted")
---> 72         time.sleep(0.5)
     73         print(username + " just logged in")
     74         logged_in = True

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Answer (score 0):

- One option is to keep a queue or list of reminders, then in the main loop of your program periodically check whether there's a reminder that needs to be sent out now. If the queue is ordered by time, you'll only need to check the first one. That will also let you keep the reminders in a persistent place (database), so they're not lost if the program is restarted; and provide facilities for changing and cancelling reminders that haven't been sent yet.
- If you don't need persistence or changing or cancelling the reminders, another option would be to do them in a separate threads or processes, one per reminder. Spin up a new thread, sleep(), then send out the reminder. That will be simpler for the basic functionality, but make it pretty much impossible to add persistence or changing or cancelling the reminders, so it's only really suitable for closed projects (ones with no future, perhaps because it's an assignment).

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to do but maybe this could help you. [Using python's smtplib, how can I send an email in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293734/using-pythons-smtplib-how-can-i-send-an-email-in-the-future).

Also, if you want to run other things while this is running you need to use multi-threading. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Other options:
You can use snakemake to make multi-threading and use other language like bash scripts in an orderly fashion way. https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. It is mostly used in bioinformatics but it could help if you are using bash, python and multi-threading to simplify your code.